# add_const won't work with forwarding references

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, type-traits

I'm using the `add_const` typetrait in a scenario where it's applied on a forwarding reference type. Everything looked like no constness was added to the type so I made a small example to verify that was the case (`PrintType` is an incomplete type that will cause a compilation error, forcing the compiler to spit out the name of the template argument in the error message) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <complex>


template <class T>
struct PrintType; 

template <class T>
void f(T&& arg)
{
    PrintType<std::add_const_t<decltype(arg)>> local; 
    (void)local; 
}


int main() 
{
    std::complex<double> co; 
    f(co); 
}
```

The error message [says](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b20486fa91e2766) :

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void f(T&&) [with T = std::complex<double>&]':

main.cpp:20:9:   required from here

main.cpp:12:48: error: 'PrintType<std::complex<double>&> local' has incomplete type

     PrintType<std::add_const_t<decltype(arg)>> local;
```

ie the trait transformed my type to `T = std::complex<double>&` instead of `T = std::complex<double> const&`

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to see `PrintType<std::complex<double> const &>` or `PrintType<std::complex<double> const &&>` based on the rvalueness of the parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type trait works as expected. You should consider what you are attempting to do, which is to add constness to a reference. **You can't rebind a reference** (it's not mutable), so essentially any reference is a `const` reference

```
T& == T& const
```

What I suppose you expect to do is to create a reference to a const type (which reminds me of the `const iterator` vs `const_iterator` thingy) which cant' be done this way, for the same reason you can't typedef a **reference** type to a **reference to a const type** this way :

```
typedef T& ref_t;
typedef const ref_t const_ref_t; // This is not T const& !!
```

To sum up, adding const to a reference type makes it a const reference (which is the same as a reference) and not a reference to a `const` type

Comment: that's exactly what I was trying do, I edited the question to mention it as well.

Answer (score 1):

For situations like these, it can be useful to have a type trait that transfers the reference to a new type. This can complement another trait that does the same for `const` and `volatile`, implemented almost identically. In your case, you *should* only need to worry about lvalue references if you use `T` instead of `decltype(arg)`. However, if using a lambda, you definitely do need to worry about rvalue references as well.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
template<typename T, bool ApplyLvalueRef, bool ApplyRvalueRef>
struct apply_ref {
    static_assert(!(ApplyLvalueRef && ApplyRvalueRef), "Improper use: T cannot be & and &&");

    using possibly_lref = std::conditional_t<
        ApplyLvalueRef,
        std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>,
        T
    >;

    using type = std::conditional_t<
        ApplyRvalueRef,
        std::add_rvalue_reference_t<possibly_lref>,
        possibly_lref
    >;
};

template<typename From, typename To>
struct transfer_ref : apply_ref<To, std::is_lvalue_reference<From>{}, std::is_rvalue_reference<From>{}> {};

template<typename From, typename To>
using transfer_ref_t = typename transfer_ref<From, To>::type;
```

At first glance, it seems a bit silly to have separate booleans for lvalue vs. rvalue. However, this allows for applying neither. There should never be a situation in which both are true, and this is enforced by the static assertion.

Now we can easily write the function:

```
template <class T>
void f(T&& arg)
{
    using with_const = std::add_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
    PrintType<transfer_ref_t<T, with_const>> local; 
    (void)local; 
}
```

Since we cannot apply `const` to a reference, we must strip it, add `const` to the referred type, and then add the reference back.